# Javascript: get image SRC from a page in another domain

Tags: javascript

I am the webmaster of two websites. The first one generates a web page with inside a dynamic image. I need to get the dynamic pseudo-random URL of this image via Javascript from the other website.

This image has an `ID="main-img"` tag.

Is there any way to get the `SRC` element of this image without using a server-side language?

I already tried with an `XMLHttpRequest` object, but at the `request.responseText` I get an empty string.

Any suggestion? Thank you.

```
    function makeHttpObject()
    {
        try {return  new XMLHttpRequest();}
        catch (error) {alert(error)}
        try {return   ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");}
        catch (error) {alert(error)}
        try {return   ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");}
        catch (error) {alert(error)}
    }

    function httpGet(theUrl)
    {
        try 
        {
            var request = makeHttpObject();
            request.open("GET", theUrl, true);
            request.send(null);
            request.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (request.readyState == 4)
                {
                    alert(request.responseText);
                }
                else
                {
                    alert('Nothing to show')
                }
            }
        }
        catch (error) {alert(error)}            
    }
```

Comment: what browser did you use? i believe you should hit browser security in regard of Cross Origin. please check the browser console.

Comment: I am using Chrome, but I would create it as cross browser.
What do you mean with "browser console"?